# How to inject data obtained from result(var) to result1(var) in golang

Tags: json, go, go-map

1. terraform.tfstate is the input file and packageservicelist.tf.json is the output file.
2. Both are converted into Map Files
3. The data which I traversed is stored in result & I want to copy the data from result to result1.
4. Will Write operations works here. If yes . How ?

```
package main

import (  
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {  
    //File Reading terraform.tfstate

    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("terraform.tfstate")
    if err != nil {
        //fmt.Println("File reading error", err)
        return
    }
// Map is save in m
    m := make(map[string]interface{})
    json.Unmarshal(data, &m)
   result:= m["resources"].([]interface{})[0].(map[string]interface{})["instances"].([]interface{})[0].(map[string]interface{})["attributes"].(map[string]interface{})["packaged_service_list"].([]interface{})[0].(map[string]interface{})["package_service"]
   fmt.Println(result)

//File Reading packageservicelist.tf.json

    data1, err :=ioutil.ReadFile("./linear/packageservicelist.tf.json")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("File reading error", err)
        return
    }

    m1 := make(map[string]interface{})
    json.Unmarshal(data1, &m1)
    fmt.Println("\n")
    result1:= m1["resource"].(map[string]interface{})["api_packageservicelist"].(map[string]interface{})["packageservicelist"].(map[string]interface{})["packaged_service_list"].(map[string]interface{})["package_service"]
    fmt.Println(result1)







}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `result` and `result1` have the value of the key `package_service` coming from different sources. You want to put `result` instead of `result1`. They, you have to write to that key:

```
m1["resource"].(map[string]interface{})["api_packageservicelist"].(map[string]interface{})["packageservicelist"].(map[string]interface{})["packaged_service_list"].(map[string]interface{})["package_service"]=result
```

Then when you write `m1`, the contents of the `package_service` from the first file will be written.

Comment: How to make it generic ?

Comment: I do not understand the question